# Jquery/Js - Find columns in Gridview in Repeater - hide them

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asprepeater

I am not excatly sure were to start with this so if you need more info please ask.

I have a .aspx page. It has on it a asp:repeater and in that repeater there is a asp:gridview.

Each repeater shows a different product's details. Each gridview in that repeater then has x amount of columns to show name, price, blah blah. The number of columns varies but there are 4 at the start with are always the same.

The name of those 4 columns I have gotten in the code behind and added them to a 'select' (drop down) on the page at the top outside everything.

The idea is that of those 4 columns only 1 is shown at a time, the one selected in the drop down.

Let's assume that my boss is a 'very flexible person' and does not want to change the structure of the page, i.e. repeater and gridview, and wants me to complete this using some js/jquery (client side - i.e. not another call to the db. -- all info sits on page and is shown or hidden on client).

**What i have tried....**

```
var singleValues = document.getElementById('<%= deliveryoption.ClientID %>').value;
```

That gets the value from the drop down -- this part works. Note: will use this value to compare against the column heading (which is in a 'th' tag).

Note: the whole table has a css class of gridDetails and the columns td and the headings is th -- obviously.... :P

Now.... the following seems to work

---

```
$('.gridDetails td').click(function () {

var singleValues = document.getElementById('<%= deliveryoption.ClientID %>').value;

var col = $(this).prevAll().length; //$(this).index; // does the same...?

var header = $(this).parents('table').find('th:nth-child(' + (col + 1) + ')');

alert(header.text());  // for testing ....

var rowIndex = col + 1;

if (header.text() == singleValues) {

$('td:nth-child(' + rowIndex + '), th:nth-child(' + rowIndex + ')').hide();

}
```

---

the problem is that it is on the event of `click` for the table.

How can I change this to be on the event of `onchange` for the drop down. I know 'how' to do that in the code to bind to the drop down lol, what I mean is, the reference to `this` in the code is then the drop down, which won't find the column etc....

Just to be clear:
- there is a runat=server  div around the outside
- then there is a repeater
- then 1 or more gridviews inside the repeater

I have read about the `.proxy()` in jquery but I don't think this will help in this case...

I think that is it... let me know if I missed anything...

Thanks in advance

Cheers
Robin

edit

The page

```
<div>
<select name="deliveryoption" id="deliveryoption" runat="server" onchange="test()">

</select>
</div>
<div id="outsidediv" runat="server" style="margin: 5px">
<asp:Repeater ID="SizeSelectionRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="SizeSelectionRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelProductCode" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelPackageQuantity" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Panel ID="SizeSelectionPanel" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:GridView ID="SizeSelectionGridView" runat="server" CssClass="gridDetails" OnRowDataBound="SizeSelectionGridView_RowDataBound"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <asp:Label ID="PriceLabelSpecial" runat="server" Width="30%" Style="display: inline;"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add to Cart">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table width="300px" style="border-style: none;">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="middle" style="border-style: none;">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Width="120px" Height="22px" 
                                    CssClass="buynow">Buy now</asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Comment: lol, yeah the design of the page is not overly friendly... but I have been told to leave it 'because it took so long to build in the first place'.... :S   Not, sure if that is a valid reason but....

Comment: Nope. It is as below at the top of the page before the repeater.

<div>
<select name="deliveryoption" id="deliveryoption" runat="server" onchange="test()">

</select>
</div>

Comment: Hard to understand your JS. Not clear why it is related to clicked TD column. As I understand - you just need to find a column where TH contains the same text as selected value of dropdown, right?

Comment: The js atm works on the event of the td click. So if I click on a column, then it gets the column and hides it. The alert is really just for testing. I need to change it from a click event on the td to a onchange for the drop down...   Essentally but yes. I need to find a column where the th contains the same text as the selected value of the dropdown and then hide that column and that column only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you can just do something like this:

```
$('#<%= deliveryoption.ClientID %>').change(function(){
    var singleValues = $(this).val();
    var thOfColumnThatShouldBeHidden = $(".gridDetails th:contains('" + singleValues + "')");
})
```

Everything else you already have. Now you can find `col` using `thOfColumnThatShouldBeHidden` the same way you do it now, but without using `$(this)` To find required TH I'm using [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

Comment: Kind of works. The problem is this line:
var col = $(thOfColumnThatShouldBeHidden).prevAll().length;

When I go to hide the col:
 $('td:nth-child(' + col + '), th:nth-child(' + col + ')').hide();

then 'col' returns the wrong value. Works for the first few columns, but if I select the 3 column, the value for col is 4. The counting seems of... it seems to count the first column and then the one i want, then the first one, then the next.. like always throws in the first column index again between each column... does that make sense...

Comment: Yeah I made a small check to see what 'col' returns.
Basically, for column 1-4 it returns

0, 2, 4, 6 respectively

Comment: I wonder if that is because there are two gridviews on the page... and both grid views have the same first 4 columns, I mean have the same column headers....

Comment: `var col = $(".gridDetails th:contains('" + singleValues + "'):first").index()`   ----   Had to use the `first` because there were two results returned. I.e. one in the top gridview and one and in the next gridview.